How does Next.js bundle code for production?
For Next.js v13+ the documentation says that Turbopack is used by default, except not for building, only for development.
If that's the case, how is code "bundled" for production by default? Do I have the choice to only transpile but not bundle code when using Next.js?
Thank you!

It still uses webpack by default. For now turbopack can only be used in development with next dev --turbo.
If you only want to transpile your code, you should try to use the babel-cli as described here.

I think it uses Webpack as bundling tool for production build. You can also customize the behavior in next.config.mjs
Check this document
